# How to report values matching Text field in row and date in column?

Tags: excel-formula

I need to match description fields in both sheet and return three of values
i.e. AVG, MIN & MAX value.

Please see below screenshots.

**DATA** SHEET AS VALUE SOURCE TO BE REPORTED IN **MAIN** SHEET

[image: **DATA** SHEET AS VALUE SOURCE TO BE REPORTED IN **MAIN** SHEET]

**MAIN** SHEET AS REPORT TO GET "AVG" VALUES FROM **DATA** SHEET BY MATCHING VALUES OF DESCRIPTION TEXT (e.g. $C16) & DATE (F$15)

[image: **MAIN** SHEET AS REPORT TO GET "AVG" VALUES FROM **DATA** SHEET BY MATCHING VALUES OF DESCRIPTION TEXT (e.g. $C16) & DATE (F$15)]

"=VLOOKUP($C16,DATA!$A$3:$W$455,MATCH(F$15,DATA!$A$1:$W$1,0),FALSE)" is not working for my requirement and reports "N/A".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paste in F16:

```
=VLOOKUP($C16,DATA!$A$3:$W$455,MATCH(F$15,DATA!$A$1:$W$1,0)+1)
```

This will only bring in the AVG. If you want all three values in the same cell:

```
=VLOOKUP($C16,DATA!$A$3:$W$455,MATCH(F$15,DATA!$A$1:$W$1,0)+1)&"/"&VLOOKUP($C16,DATA!$A$3:$W$455,MATCH(F$15,DATA!$A$1:$W$1,0)+2)&"/"&VLOOKUP($C16,DATA!$A$3:$W$455,MATCH(F$15,DATA!$A$1:$W$1,0)+3)
```

Copy and Paste accordingly